Powershell class can't call its own methods when invoked from runspace
I'm facing a weird bug where my custom class can't seem to be able to call its own functions (static or not) when it is invoked from a runspace (so, when one of its methods is called from a runspace, and that method needs to call inner methods of the class).
More specifically, it seems to hang as if it was waiting for something to end/happen and will never stop. No error is thrown, I tried "debugging" it the old way by writing to console : it is able to write lines before the inner method call but not after. And the Write-Host lines inside the inner method that it is calling won't print either so it's most likely never run.
Calling methods of the class from the runspace works, it's just the class that cannot call its own methods. Now I'm wondering, as I am using Powershell 5.1, could it be related ? Do I need Powershell 7 for this kind of usage ?
Here is how I'm initiating my runspace pool :
# Creating an initial session state and importing modules
$iss = [system.management.automation.runspaces.initialsessionstate]::CreateDefault()

$modules = @($FirstModule, $SecondModule, $ThirdModule)
foreach($module in $modules) {
    [void]$iss.ImportPSModule($module)
}

# Creating a runspace pool
$RunspacePool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, [int]$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS, $iss, $host)
$RunspacePool.ApartmentState = "MTA"
$RunspacePool.Open()
$Runspaces = $results = @()

# Some code, defining instance of Class A ...

$ScriptBlock = {
    param([Parameter()]$classInstance, [Parameter()]$item)

    # call works as intended, but code after that will never run as it hangs
    $classInstance.ProcessItem($item)
}

foreach($item in $itemlist) {
    $runspace = [PowerShell]::Create($iss)

    $null = $runspace.AddScript($ScriptBlock)
    $null = $runspace.AddParameter('classInstance', $classAInstance)
    $null = $runspace.AddParameter('item', $item)

    $runspace.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool

    $Runspaces += [PSCustomObject]@{
        Pipe = $runspace;
        Status = $runspace.BeginInvoke()
    }
}


And here is an example of Class A :
class ClassA {
    # Properties, constructor ...


    [object] SecondMethod([object]$item) {
        # Doing a Write-Host here does not work
        
        # Process of item...
        return $item
    }

    [void] ProcessItem([object]$item) {
        # Doing a Write-Host here works
        $newItem = $this.SecondMethod($item)
        # Doing a Write-Host here does not work

        # Further processing ...
    }
}

I tried using static methods instead to see if it was directly related to the class' instance but with no luck. I can't get over why this would happen. This behavior does not happen when not running the workflow inside a runspace, this is specific to it being called from a workspace (I verified it by just running one iteration of the ScriptBlock without putting it inside a runspace).

EDIT:
Here is more specific (and updated, thanks to Santiago Squarzon) details to make it easier to reproduce.
Class A is a custom GLPI API class that allows me to initiate a GLPI session by providing user key and app key. It calls a custom HTTP class that only provides static methods to make HTTP requests cleaner and more straightforward.
Here is the corresponding methods that are responsible of initiating the GLPI session :
using module '.\RestModel.psm1'

class ClassA {
    [string]$glpiUsrkey
    [string]$glpiAppkey
    [string]$glpiUrl
    [string]$sessionToken
    [Hashtable]$headers

    ClassA([string]$usrkey, [string]$appkey, [string]$url) {        
        $this.glpiUsrkey = $usrkey
        $this.glpiAppkey = $appkey
        $this.glpiUrl = $url
        $this.sessionToken = $null
    }

    [void] StartSession() {
        # Write-Host here works, but after the call to inner method it will hang
        $this.InitializeSessionToken()
        $this.headers = @{
            "Content-Type" = "application/json";
            "session-token" = $this.sessionToken;
            "App-Token" = $this.glpiAppkey
        }
    }

    [void] InitializeSessionToken() {
        $url = $this.glpiUrl + "/initSession"
        $sessionHeaders = @{
            "Content-Type" = "application/json";
            "Authorization" = "user_token $($this.glpiUsrkey)";
            "App-Token" = $this.glpiAppkey
        }
        
        $this.sessionToken = ([RestModel]::GetRequest($url, $sessionHeaders)).session_token
    }
}

Here is how GetRequest method from my HTTP class works :
using module '.\ExceptionsModel.psm1'

class RestModel {

    static [object] GetRequest([string]$url, [object]$headers) {
        try {
            $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Method Get
            return $response
        } catch {         
            throw [CustomRestException]::new("Error while performing GET request on $url. ($_)", $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__)
        }
    }
}

And here is the updated code of the runspace creation :
$ScriptBlock = {
    param([Parameter()]$glpiManager, [Parameter()]$item)
    
    $glpiManager.StartSession()     # Same problem as before
    $classInstance.ProcessItem($item)
    $glpiManager.EndSession()
}

foreach($item in $itemlist) {
    # variables are created with valid values beforehand
    $glpiManager = [ClassA]::new($glpi_usrkey, $glpi_appkey, $glpi_url)

    $runspace = [PowerShell]::Create($iss)
    $null = $runspace.AddScript($ScriptBlock)

    $null = $runspace.AddParameter('glpiManager', $glpiManager)
    $null = $runspace.AddParameter('item', $item)

    $runspace.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool

    $Runspaces += [PSCustomObject]@{
        Pipe = $runspace;
        Status = $runspace.BeginInvoke()
    }
}


There is no $classAInstance = [ClassA]::new() before .AddParameter('classInstance', $classAInstance) ? Is that a typo ?

The class instance is instanciated before (outside the loop), I did not bother to add it as I thought it would be obvious that I wouldn't even be able to call the class' method from the runspace without it. The instance is shared among the runspaces, would that be part of the problem ?

A single instance shared among all runspaces ? Sounds like your issue is thread-safety then.

That's a fair point, I don't know why I didn't think of that. Though this doesn't seem to be the problem, creating a new instance for each runspace does not solve the problem. I think this might be specific with the nature of my class. Class A is a custom GLPI API class, that calls methods from a custom HTTP class. When initiating GLPI session from the ScriptBlock (by calling a method from class A instance) it has the same problem : instance is never created and code hangs at this line, anything after will never run. I can share more specific code if necessary.

As of now your question doesnt show a way of a minimal way of reproducing the issue so yes

I updated my question with more specific code.

shouldn't $glpiManager = [GlpiApi]::new($glpi_usrkey, $glpi_appkey, $glpi_url) be $glpiManager = [ClassA]::new($glpi_usrkey, $glpi_appkey, $glpi_url)?

Yes that's a typo sorry, tried my best to pinpoint what I had to change to stay coherent with my previous examples, GlpiApi is the actual class name in my code.

You have to add the class variable in the Initialsessionstate, not pass it as a parameter like so:
class TestClass {
    $VarA = 0
    TestClass() {}
    MethodA() {
        $this.VarA++
    }
}

$TestClass = [TestClass]::new()
$initialSessionState = [system.management.automation.runspaces.initialsessionstate]::CreateDefault()

$var = Get-Variable 'TestClass'
$runspaceVariable = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.SessionStateVariableEntry -ArgumentList $var.name, $var.value, $null
$InitialSessionState.Variables.Add($runspaceVariable)

$RunspacePool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, [int]$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS, $InitialSessionState, $host)
$RunspacePool.Open()

$Powershell = [PowerShell]::Create()
$Powershell.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
$null = $Powershell.AddScript({
    $TestClass.MethodA()
})
$Powershell.Invoke()

$TestClass.VarA # MethodA was invoked and this returns 1


So the class instance will be shared across all runspaces ? Wouldn't that cause thread safety issues like Santiago Squarzon mentioned ?

It will only cause issues if a property/variable is being modified at the same time by calling methods from different runspaces, which doesn't look like it from your example. If your case is that complex, then a solution would be to include System.Threading.Monitor or System.Collections.Concurrent.

Yeah it shouldn't be an issue, I just wanted to know if PS had a weird implementation of multi threading and did things in the background that would cause a thread safety issue. Thanks for the answer, will try when I'll be back to my office.

Unfortunately this still does not work. Calling a class instance function within the scriptblock works (as it always did), but the class instance cannot call its own methods.

it's likely RestModel is not defined in your runspacepool.
